# Jquery Datepicker is not working in Ajax tab container

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

I have one ajax tabcontainer in asp.net page.
I am using jquery to popup calender when click on Textbox which is in Ajax tabcontainer.

When the textbox is outside of the ajax tabcontainer its working fine. But when I am putting this textbox into ajax tab container the Jquery for datepicket is not working to popup the Calender. How can I solve this issue?

This is the code I'm using to bind the date picker to my textbox.

```
  $(function () {
            var d = new Date();
            var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
            $('#txtDob').live('load', function () {
                $("#txtDob").datepicker(
       { yearRange: '1900:' + curr_year, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, maxDate: '0' });

            });
            $('#txtDOD').live('load', function () {
                $("#txtDOD").datepicker(
       { yearRange: '1900:' + curr_year, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, maxDate: '0' });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your html and check the ClientIDs.

A good practice is to always use the client ids in javascript.

like this:

```
 $('#<%= txtDob.ClientID %>')
```

Comment: I have tried this but getting Error "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: Seems you are adding controls dynamically too. Inspect your html, the clientID will be different when inside a container

Answer (score 0):

While you are using Dynamic controls, one of the things you can do is to set the ClientID mode of your txtDob control to AutoID

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDob" runat="server" CssClass="hasDatePicker" ClientIDMode="AutoID"/>
```

The ClientID value is generated by concatenating the ID values of each parent naming container with the ID value of the control. In data-binding scenarios where multiple instances of a control are rendered, an incrementing value is inserted in front of the control's ID value. Each segment is separated by an underscore character (_)